# How does "столько X, что Y" compare with "так X, что Y"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Он **так** увлёкся уборкой, **что** потерял счет времени.

The structure "так X, что Y" means "so (much) X that Y", with Action X leading to **End Result** Y. I'm wondering if "столько X, что Y" works the same way: Action X vs End Result Y?

> Я **столько** раз пытался связаться с ней, **что** потерял счет.

Or is it more like "so (many times) X **to the extent of** Y", with Y not being so much about the end result as about the **surprising degree** to which X?

Comment: the 1st proposition is accurate, this construction is also used with такой/ая/ие etc. and столькие in different inflexions save for nominal which is reserved for столько

Comment: the meaning implied in the 2nd proposition could be achieved with addition of **аж/буквально** after **что**, where **аж** is of low register

Comment: There is an idiom of ever increasing demands that follows the first structure, *"Дайте водички попить, а то так кушать хочется, аж переночевать негде"*

Answer (score 1):

These are very similar constructs.

If you reformulate these sentences into questions in English:

> How carried away did he get with the cleaning? So that he lost track of time.
>
> How many times did I try to reach out to her? So many times that I lost count.

, you can notice that these questions allow an answer with a quantifier: "much", "little", "more than you" etc.

English has one generic interrogative for questions like these, namely "how": "how much", "how long" etc.

Russian, however, has at least one more: *сколько*, and the corresponding determiner *столько*. In English, it's just a variety of "how" ("how much" or "how many"), with corresponding "so" ("so much" or "so many").

This way you can probably see that both these constructs are in fact varieties of the generic "so ... that", except in Russian "so much" has its own word (*столько*) while others are just the generic "so" (*так*).

So *столько раз, что* just means "so many times that", and is not at all different from other "so ... that" constructs which are conveyed by *так ... что*.

In fact you can even rephrase the original Russian sentence this way:

> Я так много раз пытался связаться с ней, что потерял счет.

which makes it parallel the other one even better.

Answer (score 0):

**"Так ... что ..."** is a composite sentence where the action in the first clause leads to the result in the second clause. It is different from the second structure in that the action in the first clause occurs once.

> Так наелся, что пришлось некоторое время посидеть молча. *// He ate so much that he had to sit quietly for a while.*

**"Столько ... что ..."** the action in the first clause was repeated multiple times, which leads to the result in the second clause. The result is not a surprise, but a conclusion based on logic, or experience.

> Я столько слышал, что в метро много потрясающе красивых станций, а сам вот посмотришь ― все они почти одинаковые. *// I heard so much about extremely beautiful subway stations, but they look almost the same to me.*

Comment: in the 2nd example что is related not to столько, but to слышал, in order for the sentence to illustrate the construction it should look something like  Я **столько** слышал, что в метро много потрясающе красивых станций, **что** мне захотелось побывать на каждой из них